# Updating a GitHub iOS SDK without overwriting custom changes

Tags: ios, xcode, github-for-mac

About a year ago I built an iOS app for my Company using the Shopify mobile buy sdk located at:
https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios

While customizing this app to suit my company's needs, I made numerous customizations to this sdk, changing many of the core files, and completely changing the storyboard. Since then, I've kind of let it sit and have been focused on other non iOS projects.

Now to my question - I need to update my app to include the latest modifications of the base SDK for swift 5.0.

Essentially, I think the question I'm asking is how do I merge these two repositories, added the necessary changes, and not overwriting my custom changes.

I've been doing a bunch of searching, and I don't think I'm using the right terminology to get to the answer I need. I might have not even titled this question appropriately...

I think what I need to do is "merge two repositories" using the GitHub app where I can see the changes that will be made, line by line, and approve the necessary ones. However, I'm having trouble finding a suitable guide on how to start this process.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle the problem appropriately, or even just a link to an article that accurately describes the problem I'm facing. Thanks!

Comment: You should have forked Shopify and checked your changes in on a branch. In that case, merging in the upstream changes is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yea I'm learning that now, it was my first app, and at the time I was very green. Is it possible to fork it now?

Comment: Have you been under version control locally all along?

Comment: Yes. Initially I cloned the repository into GitHub desktop, then modified from that. That allowed me to see changes made to the base SDK, and choose if I wanted to apply those changes. Since then I've changed Mac's, and the only thing that survived was the project folder. This lost my connection to the base SDK and version control.

Comment: Really? When you copy a folder from one place to another, if it is under git control, the git repository comes along for the ride. Or you could have checked in to a remote repository, changed to the new computer, and cloned the remote repository. If you've been developing for any length of time with no version control at all, it's hard to sympathize, let alone advise.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. I wish I had spent more time learning proper version control, instead of just diving head into code when I started this project. That being said, using your advice I pulled the local repository into GitHub and found that it had indeed kept the information. I see the following branches in GitHub desktop that are available to me: "master" and "develop". The master branch shows it was last updated a year ago, and the "develop" branch  4 days ago. It looks like I was working under the master branch, as I can see the changes I made in there.

Comment: When I select "pull origin" I am prompted to resolve conflict before I can merge. Is there hope?

Comment: If I switch branches to "develop", I can see the current version of the SDK being presented. Is it possible to merge my changes into this branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the bellow step, so that you can find modifications between the branches.
1. New pull request
2. select "base" & "compare" branches.
you can easily find the changes as well as conflicts also.